# Save file dialog - path not working

Tags: c#, wpf, savefiledialog

App.config:

```
<add key="SaveDraftPath" value="C:\Drafts\"/>
```

C#:

```
var saveDraftPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SaveDraftPath"]; 
var sfDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
sfDialog.InitialDirectory = saveDraftPath;
sfDialog.FileName = "FILE";
```

For some reason this doesn't open the filebrowser in the path like planned, any one know why or how to fix?

I've tried this now, still doesn't work:

```
var saveDraftPath = Path.GetFullPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SaveDraftPath"]);
MessageBox.Show("does directory exist : " + Directory.Exists(saveDraftPath));
var sfDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
sfDialog.InitialDirectory = saveDraftPath;
sfDialog.FileName = "FILE";
```

and Directory.Exists(saveDraftPath) returns true.. Hmmm?!

**Edit:** The above code has worked once for me. The code works for everyone who has so far answered. But it is still not working. So I suspect the problem is some sort of local/history setting stopping it. Does anyone know why this might happen?

Comment: This works okay for me.  Does the `c:\drafts` directory definitely exist on the machine?

Comment: it sure does. I tested that. It actually worked once then when I added in the line giving it default name of FILE it stopped working... hmmm...

Comment: i actually have another line to open it obviously var clickedOk = sfDialog.ShowDialog();

Comment: could it be some local settings overriding the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

> var path = Path.GetFullPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SaveDraftPath"])

Have a look at [**Path**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd170076.aspx) Class as well, has got several helpful **[methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_members.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me (getting the correct path from the config)

```
var saveDraftPath =
           ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SaveDraftPath"];
        var sfDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfDialog.InitialDirectory = saveDraftPath;
        sfDialog.FileName = "FILE";

        if (sfDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
```

see for more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx